# jupyter notebook: show seaborn plot again

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, facet

Trying to build seaborn FacetGrid plots in a Jupyter notebook. Upon creation, it displays just fine. But if I manipulate the chart and want to see it again, I cannot. I can only get the object listing.

How can I show the chart a second time?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to state the figure in a new cell to let it be displayed with the inline backend.

```
g.fig
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your code example? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Energya The OP tried to state `plt.show()`, `g` and `g.show()`. Those do not work. Instead you need to use `g.fig`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks very much! Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Uh, good question... The fact that `g.fig` gets you a matplotlib figure is not documented in seaborn I think. The place to look for when exactly a matplotlib figure is shown would be the IPython docs.

Answer (score 2):

`g.fig` doesn't work.Instead, `g.figure` works out.